# How to check if dropdown is selected

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

I'm trying to do a user management page in asp .net/c#. I create a dropdown to select the user and then save the permissions. I want to add a check if the user is correctly selected but I wouldn't even know where to start.

```
<div class="p-a-1">
    <select class="form-control" style="overflow:auto;" id="Username">
        <option id="tipoUtente" value="0">&lt;Selezionare un utente&gt;</option>
        @foreach (var utente in
    GestioneUtenti.Select(new WhereStatementBuilder { { GestioneUtenti.Empty.Ruolo, Operator.Equals, 2} }))
        {
            <option value="@utente.IdUser">@utente.Username</option>
        }
    </select>
</div>
```